# how can I fix discord.py button click event

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make if I click discord button. then bot send button label. but this is not work. I think button click event is wrong. when I launch code there is no error. but I click button nothing happens. discord.py version is 2.0.0a3575+g45d498c

```
import discord
from discord.ui import Button, View, view
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import time
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}!")

class QueView(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for i in range(5):
            self.add_item(Button(label=f"{i+1}", custom_id=f"{i}"))
            
@bot.command()
async def Butt(ctx):
    view = QueView()
    max_time = time.time() + (20)
    await ctx.send("hi", view = view)
    while time.time() < max_time:
        res = await bot.wait_for('button_click')
        print(f'{res.component.label}')
    print("timeout")
```

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe discord.py has a `button_click` event. Instead, you could wait for an interaction like so:

```
# Wait for interaction with a component_type of 2 (button) and that has a custom id
res = await bot.wait_for('interaction', check=lambda interaction: interaction.data["component_type"] == 2 and "custom_id" in interaction.data.keys())

# loop through the children of the view and get the button with corresponding custom_id
for item in view.children:
    if item.custom_id == res.data["custom_id"]:
        button = item
print(f'{button.label}')
```